# How do I create launcher icon for Chromium with proxy?

Tags: chromium, proxy, .desktop

I use proxy to connect to the network of my employer. However, I do not use any proxy for my personal use. So when I work, I open chromium in command line via the command

```
chromium --proxy-server="http://xxxxxxxxxx:yyyy"
```

This works fine but I would like to have a launcher icon which would do this automatically so that I don't need to use command line.
I know that all I need to do is to create a `.desktop` file and save it to `~/.local/share/applications`. But I have zero experience with creating `.desktop` files so my only chance is to modify the existing chromium.desktop file. However, I did not find this file anywhere.

Could you please help me with creating the desktop file for launching chromium with proxy? Or tell me where the `chromium.desktop` file is located at least?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an new empty text file in `~/.local/share/applications` and open with a text editor. Then add the following lines to it.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Chromium with Proxy
Comment=Launch Chromium with proxy
Exec=chromium --proxy-server="http://xxxxxxxxxx:yyyy"
Type=Application
Icon=chromium
Terminal=false
```

Then save the file as a `.desktop` file, say as `chromium-proxy.desktop`.

You can learn more about desktop entry specifications at [freedesktop.org](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html).

Also look into the `/usr/share/applications/` directory for the pre-installed `.desktop` launcher for Chromium. If Chromium is installed as a snap then it should be at `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`. Note that in your file manager it might not show up as a file with a `.desktop` suffix, rather you should see a Chromium icon just with the name 'Chromium'.